# Counting number of one's in a binay number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

how does this code works

for example

```
input: 5(101)
ouput: 2
```

the function is

```
scanf("%d", &a);
while(a)
{
oneina++;
a=a&(a-1);
}
printf("%d", oneina);
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid read the title.

Comment: Take a pencil and paper and try to figure what `a=a&(a-1)` does.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid so then what do you think it should do, frankly? It is **entirely obvious** that it should (and does) count the number of ones in the binary representation of a given integer.

Comment: Err, what? I suppose you're asking *how* the code works? I don't understand the question here.

Comment: sorry for my English, I am expecting a solution in the form of a general derivation(for all cases) rather than the explanation of the example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a-1` is `a` with the first `1` (from right) occurring in `a` as `0` and all the bits to the right of that bit as `1`. So when you bitwise and them, you remove one `1` from `a` at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d", &a);      // a = 0111b (7)

while(a)              // a = 0111b (7) : TRUE

   oneina++;          // oneina 0 --> 1

   a=a & (a-1);       // a = 0111b (7) & 0110b (6) = 0110b (6)

while(a)              // a = 0110b (6) : TRUE

   oneina++;          // oneina 1 --> 2

   a=a & (a-1);       // a = 0110b (6) & 0101b (5) = 0100b (4)

while(a)              // a = 0100b (4) : TRUE

   oneina++;          // oneina 2 --> 3

   a=a & (a-1);       // a = 0100b (4) & 0011b (3) = 0000b (0)

while(a)              // a = 0000b (4) : FALSE

printf("%d", oneina); // '3'
```